# Firebase node.js push async

Tags: node.js, firebase

Trying to use Firebase as a nodejs module. And i have a problem:

Firebase docs say to code for nodejs the same as for javascript Firebase library.

```
var newChildRef = myRootRef.push{{name: "Child1"}, function(error){
   if(!error){
     myModel.addChildto(newChildRef); // Here is calling global var inside a callback!   
   }
});
```

In nodejs we need to use async calls to databases. So the standard node way is:

```
 myRootRef.push{{name: "Child1"}, function(newChildRef,error){
       if(!error){
         myModel.addChildto(newChildRef); 
       }
    });
```

Please explain how should I code in node js using Firebase, not to spoil an async style.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/eEsFpjE2mmI

The short answer is that it's better to use an inline function for each operation you do. We'll look into improving the API so it's easier to use the same callback for multiple `set` and `push` calls.